# Plotting multiple corrplots (R) in the same graph

Tags: r, plot, correlation, r-corrplot

Is it possible to plot several `corrplot` graphs in a single graph?

Reproducible example:

```
library(corrplot)
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)

col1 <- colorRampPalette(c("#7F0000","red","#FF7F00","yellow","white", "cyan", "#007FFF", "blue","#00007F"))

corrplot(M, method="color", col=col1(20), cl.length=21,order = "AOE", addCoef.col="grey")
corrplot(M, method="square", col=col1(200),order = "AOE")
corrplot(M, method="ellipse", col=col1(200),order = "AOE")
corrplot(M, method="shade", col=col1(20),order = "AOE")
```

I am wondering if there is a function similar to "Multiple plot function" suitable for this purpose. I want all these corrplots in the same output.

Comment: Reproducible example?

Comment: The package `corrplot` does this; see [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/corrplot.pdf) for details.

Comment: question updated based on @Pascal's suggestion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure it is. Just use `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` in your script:

```
library(corrplot)
data(mtcars)
M <- cor(mtcars)

col1 <- colorRampPalette(c("#7F0000","red","#FF7F00","yellow","white", "cyan", "#007FFF", "blue","#00007F"))

#this is my only addition
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

corrplot(M, method="color", col=col1(20), cl.length=21,order = "AOE", addCoef.col="grey")
corrplot(M, method="square", col=col1(200),order = "AOE")
corrplot(M, method="ellipse", col=col1(200),order = "AOE")
corrplot(M, method="shade", col=col1(20),order = "AOE")
```

And you are done:

[image]

Note that in `par(mfrow=c(2,2))` the first `2` represents the rows and the second `2` represents the columns. You can change that to whatever you like. I chose to have your 4 graphs presented like that because it looks nice, but you could ,say, have them all in one row if you like by using `par(mfrow=c(1,4))` (1 row, 4 columns).