# Print multiple corrplots (R) in the figure

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I am working with corrplot and following example here [Plotting multiple corrplots (R) in the same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497960/plotting-multiple-corrplots-r-in-the-same-graph) I can display multiple corrplots(R) in the same graph. However I would like to save to a tiff file and because I working with loop I don't know how to achieve this. See code below.

I loop through several block of my experiments (Block1, block2) and plot the corrplot one next to another. This works. I don't understand how to direct to tiff file. In particular where to put

tiff(file = 'Figure4Plots.tiff', width = 12, height = 12, units = "in", res = 300) and dev.off() I tried after dflist and several others but does not work Thanks!

```
dflist<-c('Block1', 'Block2') 

par(mfrow=c(2,2))

for (i in seq_along(dflist)) {
#Subset different Blocks
dataCorr<- subset(total , (block == dflist[i] ))

p.mat <- cor.mtest(dataCorr)
M<-cor(dataCorr)

col <- colorRampPalette(c("#BB4444", "#EE9988", "#FFFFFF", "#77AADD", "#4477AA"))
corrplot(M, method="color", col=col(200),  
       type="upper",  title = title,
       addCoef.col = "black", # Add coefficient of correlation
       tl.col="red", tl.srt=45, #Text label color and rotation
       # Combine with significance
       p.mat = p.mat, sig.level = 0.05, insig = "blank", 
       diag=TRUE,
      mar=c(0,0,1,0) )}
```

Comment: Do you want all plots to appear in the one tiff file? What doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: smacdonald, thanks! Yes, I would like all plots to appear in one tiff file and so far my various attempts only managed to get a tiff file only including one

Comment: I don't have your original data, but try the code in my answer below and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your original data, and I'm not familiar with the corrplot package, so I've made some dummy data and used just a simple `plot()` function. Unless there's something particular about the `corrplot()` function, you should be able to enclose most of your code in a `tiff()` block, like this:

```
dflist <- c('Block1', 'Block2', 'Block3', 'Block4') 

total <- data.frame(block=sample(dflist, size=100, replace=TRUE), x=runif(100), y=runif(100)*2)

tiff(file = 'Figure4Plots.tiff', width = 12, height = 12, units = "cm", res = 72)

    par(mfrow=c(2,2))

    for (thisBlock in dflist) {

        #Subset different Blocks
        dataCorr <- subset(total , (block == thisBlock ))
        dataCorr <- dataCorr[, c('x', 'y')]

        plot(dataCorr)
    }

dev.off()
```

This code produces `Figure4Plots.tiff`:

[image]